# Which is the fastest way to remove MongoDB documents by Date?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In our company we have a retention of eight days of data (with one million of records aprox.) so we have a cronjob that remove documents older than eight days each day. Now we're using the Published field and **this field is not indexed**.

It takes like 15 minutes to finish to get rid off 100.000 records and we found that this operation is too long.

This is the query where 'docs' is a variable with an array of documents that we don't want to remove. The 'theDate' variable is the date of eight days ago.

```
records.remove( { "Published" : { $lte : theDate }, "_id" : { $nin : docs }  }
```

**Would be it better to use the _id field**, which is indexed, in ordered to do this operation? **How can we use the _id field in order to do the same operation?**

Comment: Why don't you index that field?

Comment: Yes, you're probably right and we should create  a plain index on the Published field. The reason why we're not doing that is trying to keep simple and reasonable the amount and kind of indexes. And if we can perform this action with the _id field then, better. :) Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Discard the Cron job entirely: this is a job for TTL indexes. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/

Create a TTL index on the `Published` field with `expireAfterSeconds: 691200` and watch as your documents are automatically removed 8 days after publication.

And if you don't want to indiscriminately delete all documents 8 days after their publication, keep your Cron job and just create a plain index on the `Published` field.

Comment: We've worked with TTL indexes and it was fantastic. The problem was that we need to keep some documents. So yes, maybe the best way is to create the plain index on the Published field. I'm going to wait a bit in order to see if we're getting more possible solutions but I probably will mark this one as correct answer. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @miduga If you want to protect some documents against expiration, you may set the corresponding TTL field to some non-date type (for example, set it to null). [From the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data): _"If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that holds a date value(s), the document will not expire."_